# iPhone não lê acentos corretamente em QR CODE que funciona normalmente no Android

Tags: php, qrcode

Estou gerando um QR code de um VCARD usando o PHP QR Code (http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net) e funciona perfeitamente (tirando um problema ao salvar em SVG que vou pesquisar melhor primeiro).

Enfim, no momento o problema é que o mesmo QR code funciona corretamente no Android e não funciona corretamente no iPhone.

O problema está na acentuação. Caracteres estranhos são exibidos no lugar dos ç, ã, etc...

Alguma ideia? Já pesquisei e não achei a solução.

```
<?php 

include('phpqrcode/qrlib.php'); 

// how to build raw content - QRCode with detailed Business Card (VCard) 
$tempDir = ""; 

// here our data 
$name         = 'João Carlos da Silva'; 
$sortName     = 'da Silva;João Carlos'; 
$phone        = '+55 (89) 2345-6789'; 
$phonePrivate = '+55 (94) 4521-3989'; 
$phoneCell    = '+55 (66) 1234-5678'; 
$orgName      = 'GH Construtora'; 

$email        = 'emaildousuario@dominio.com.br'; 

// if not used - leave blank! 
$addressLabel     = 'Escritório'; 
$addressPobox     = ''; 
$addressExt       = '2º andar'; 
$addressStreet    = 'Av. das Nações, 200'; 
$addressTown      = 'Cidade'; 
$addressRegion    = 'SP';
$addressPostCode  = '18.902-100'; 
$addressCountry   = 'Brasil'; 

// we building raw data 
$codeContents  = 'BEGIN:VCARD'."\n"; 
$codeContents .= 'VERSION:2.1'."\n"; 
$codeContents .= 'N:'.$sortName."\n"; 
$codeContents .= 'FN:'.$name."\n"; 
$codeContents .= 'ORG:'.$orgName."\n"; 

$codeContents .= 'TEL;WORK;VOICE:'.$phone."\n"; 
$codeContents .= 'TEL;HOME;VOICE:'.$phonePrivate."\n"; 
$codeContents .= 'TEL;TYPE=cell:'.$phoneCell."\n"; 

$codeContents .= 'ADR;TYPE=work;'. 
    'LABEL="'.$addressLabel.'":' 
    .$addressPobox.';' 
    .$addressExt.';' 
    .$addressStreet.';' 
    .$addressTown.';' 
    .$addressPostCode.';' 
    .$addressCountry 
."\n"; 

$codeContents .= 'EMAIL:'.$email."\n"; 

$codeContents .= 'END:VCARD'; 

// generating 
QRcode::png($codeContents, $tempDir.'026.png', QR_ECLEVEL_L, 7); 

// displaying 
echo '<img src="026.png" />';
```

[image: Android][image: iPhone]

Comment: O maior problema que eu vi, olhando por cima a documentação do seu link, é que o encoder mencionado não tem uma config para o usuário definir qual das diversas maneiras de codificar caracteres especiais do QR será usada. E o outro problema é que você não mencionou na pergunta em qual encoding você salvou seu código fonte.

Comment: Não achei como definir a codificação dentro da API, mas o correto seria usar UTF-8, correto? Meu arquivo está como UTF-8.

Comment: Se alguém souber de outra API similar a esta que não tenha esse problema, eu posso alterar sem problemas já que ainda estou no começo do desenvolvimento do sistema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi a questão. Apesar de parecer ser um problema de encoding, não era pois já estava tudo em UTF-8. O problema na verdade é mais simples, esse código foi retirado da página de exemplos do PHP QR Code, porém ele seta a versão do VCARD como 2.1 como na linha abaixo. Eu simplesmente mudei para 3.0 e resolveu meu problema tanto no iOS quanto no Android.

```
$codeContents .= 'VERSION:2.1'."\n";
```

Trocar para:

```
$codeContents .= 'VERSION:3.0'."\n";
```